# AirMac server os X application does not connect with iPhone Airplay

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos, airplay

My Application requirement is develop app like(reflector/AirServer)So i Downloaded Airmac Application source and run it in mac system with X-code6.1,It did show airplay option in iPhone.Then use the following command in terminal to enable airplay option in iPhone it showing airplay button and mirroring switch button,Later i switch the mirroring button the Airmac application won't connect with iPhone and the airplay button disable after 10sec

---

The source code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/airmac/)

```
# terminal commands to enable airplay option
$ dns-sd -R 685B3599DDE1@iosAnshtech’sMacmini _raop._tcp local 49152 "txtvers=1" "ch=2" "cn=0,1" "et=0,3" "sv=false" "da=true" "sr=44100" "ss=16" "pw=false" "vn=65537" "tp=TCP,UDP" "md=0,1,2" "vs=104.29" "am=AppleTV2,1" "sf=0x4”

$ dns-sd -R "iosAnshtech’sMacmini" _airplay._tcp local 7000 "srcvers=150.33" "model=AppleTV3,1" "features=0x100029FF" "deviceid=68:5B:35:99:DD:E1"
```

Comment: Use correct tags. Why is that post tagged as Obj-C question?

Comment: because of my mac application develop using the objective-c

Comment: mirroring uses tcp7100